# How to give a product with specific SKU free with any other product in Magento

Tags: magento

I want to apply Coupon Rule such that if Customer add  Product with SKU 123 to his cart and apply coupon code,then he should get product with SKU 456 as free to his cart and discount of 100.
I know we can apply the rules from Shipping Rules but I don't know where to add SKU for free product and weather we can give 2 Product free and discount at same time.

Comment: The product with sku 456 is available free only after coupen code applied ?

Answer (score -1):

You will need to use a module. This thing is not implemented natively in Magento as far as I know.

I use [J2T autoadd](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/j2t-auto-add-va.html) for this purpose. I am sure some other exist but I did not test.